# Values in vertical bars using IN operator - SQL

Tags: sql, syntax

I encountered a query where several values are enclosed in vertical bars further to an IN opertor.
Can anyone please advise on the use and effect of the vertical bars in this scenario?

Example:

```
SELECT businesspa0_.C_BP_Group_ID AS C1_139_0_,
FROM C_BP_Group businesspa0_
WHERE businesspa0_.C_BP_Group_ID in( |713643BF6582479BAD2AF21B80836AA2|, |EAF66367C3D04B30A2F3A1E953A6E703|, |26A1FE81E1EA4A6E8D3517E8232264D1|, |1B7DCAD27AF64D16ADCFB4EBE8600078|, |A61E061A702547BB8E1D6B749B4A502A|)
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL.  It must be some bespoke syntax, probably supported by the tool used to generate the SQL.  It could also be specific to a particular database, although it does not look at all familiar to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

I do not believe that `|` means anything in the SQL standard.  The double vertical bar, `||`, is used for string concatenation.

That said, in many databases, `|` is used as an infix, bitwise `or` operator.  That is clearly not the use in this case, because there is no "left" operator for the first use.

There may be some database that supports single vertical bars as something that would make sense in this context.

You are probably totally aware that strings should be enclosed in single quotes.  Your values look like binary Hex values.  How these are represented on input depends on the database.  For instance, in Postgres, this would be:

```
x'A61E061A702547BB8E1D6B749B4A502A'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The query was automatically generated by a CRM web application I'm using. Was wondering why the vertical bars appear instead of the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't  true SQL syntax .
You can use this query like below:

```
SELECT businesspa0_.C_BP_Group_ID AS C1_139_0_,
FROM C_BP_Group businesspa0_
WHERE businesspa0_.C_BP_Group_ID in( '713643BF6582479BAD2AF21B80836AA2', 'EAF66367C3D04B30A2F3A1E953A6E703', '26A1FE81E1EA4A6E8D3517E8232264D1', '1B7DCAD27AF64D16ADCFB4EBE8600078', 'A61E061A702547BB8E1D6B749B4A502A')
```